# How to delete a character selected with Range.setStart/setEnd?

Tags: javascript

The following code listen to events assigned to a div. Pressing `h` selects the next character to the left. Pressing `l` selects the next character to the right.

```
  // HTML
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>

  // JS
  e.preventDefault()

  const range = document.createRange()
  const content = e.target.querySelector('p').firstChild

  if (e.keyCode === 72) { // h
    range.setStart(content, this.start -= 1)
    range.setEnd(content, this.end -= 1)
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 76) { // l
    range.setStart(content, this.start += 1)
    range.setEnd(content, this.end += 1)
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 88) { // x
    range.selectNode(content)
    range.deleteContents()
  }

  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  window.getSelection().addRange(range)
```

Pressing `x` is supposed to remove the selected character. The best I could accomplish was with `range.selectNode(content)` but this removes ALL the characters.

How to only remove the selected character?

**EDIT:** CodePen: http://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/QNZeQy (Click on the text and then you can press the keys and see the selection move.)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Without that it's hard to tell where your code is going wrong.

Comment: @DavidG I just created one. Please see my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `range.selectNode(content)` from your code, it select all text in `p`.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('editable')
const range = document.createRange()
const content = input.querySelector('p').firstChild
let start = 0
let end = 1

range.setStart(content, 0)
range.setEnd(content, 1)

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  if (e.keyCode === 72) { // h
    range.setStart(content, start -= 1)
    range.setEnd(content, end -= 1)
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 76) { // l
    range.setStart(content, start += 1)
    range.setEnd(content, end += 1)
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 88) { // l
    //range.selectNode(content)
    range.deleteContents()
  }
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  window.getSelection().addRange(range)
});
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks.